# Mac unable to boot memtest86 usd drive

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, bootable-disk

I've just downloaded [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com), written it to a USB flash drive using [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/), but I'm unable to boot from it. I can't see it in the boot options.

What am I doing wrong?

The main issue is my Mac keeps restarting randomly and I'd like to check if RAM is okay.

Comment: The link is directly to the download; better if it was to the page containing the download, then people don't need the payload to see what it's supposed to be.

Comment: Why are you using Etcher?  The [official MemTest](https://www.memtest86.com/technical.htm) site gives instructions on how to create a bootable USB with virtually every platform - Windows, macOS, and Linux.  For Windows, they include a utility that creates it for you.  Have you tried any of the *official* methods?

Comment: As far as your Mac restarting randomly, also try it in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting).  You can do it before or after running MemTest.  Keep in mind - the randomly rebooting part will be a different question than this one

Comment: I also have a problem booting from a MemTest86 boot USB. This on a 2017 iMac (not T2 chip). I tried three different USB drives: a spinning drive and two thumb drives. When I boot holding down the Option key, the Mac lists two bootable drives: the internal drive and a bootable clone, but never the MemTest USB drive.